# Why no `seq` in `accursedUnutterablePerformIO`?

Tags: haskell, ghc, unsafe-perform-io

Why is `accursedUnutterablePerformIO` (aka `inlinePerformIO`) implemented

```
accursedUnutterablePerformIO :: IO a -> a
accursedUnutterablePerformIO (IO a) = case a realWorld# of (# _, r #) -> r
```

and not

```
accursedUnutterablePerformIO :: IO a -> a
accursedUnutterablePerformIO (IO a) = case a realWorld# of (# s, r #) -> s `seq` r
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, `realWorld#` [doesn't exist runtime](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#t:RealWorld), therefore we can't do any computation on it, thus `seq` doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Duh.  `State#` is unlifted, therefore `seq` on it is a no-op.

Comment: Also true, but I think runtime non-existence is a more salient (and unique among unlifted types) feature.

Comment: I just went digging and can't seem to find where `realWorld#` is exported. Obviously, it's primitive so it won't have a real definition, but where can I get it?

Comment: @AndrásKovács, it's not unique any more. There's another one that's polykinded: `Proxy#`, "constructed" by `proxy#`. The documentation (in `GHC.Prim`) of the kind of `Proxy#` is a bit vague.

Comment: @dfeuer It's in `GHC.Prim` (home) or `GHC.Exts` (where you should import it from)

Comment: `realWorld#` is not on the export list in `GHC.Prim`. It's highly wired-in and probably [this](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/a008eadfaa4816be349b4fefde9b9b9edc1ca359/compiler/basicTypes/MkId.hs) and [this](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/206a8bf4665af216784357f6741ccf5e68dd2495/compiler/prelude/PrelNames.hs) come closest to definition sites. All I did was some name search though, so I could be wrong here.